# ASP.Net MVC Specify current page class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to put a class on an a tag dependant on the current route, can this be done?

I haven't used ActionLinks at the moment but should be able to switch to them if I need to, if possible I'd like to avoid it simply for having to change all the navigation.

For example if I have:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/About">About</a>
etc
```

If navigate to /About I would want this to change to:
    About

Comment: You really need to put a bit more effort into your questions, the answers will be much less abstract. Had a concrete example been placed into the question (i.e. I'm not asking for a **ton of effort**) the answer would have been more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to switch to HTML Helpers to us ActionLinks you can stick with the classic links you have and use Html.Raw to output raw html.

```
 <a href="/" @Html.Raw("class=\"someclasshere\"")>Home</a>
```

The conditionally set the class like the current "active" navigation you should be looking at both the controller and the action, something like:

```
 <a href="/" @Html.Raw(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Equals("index",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Equals("home",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)? "class=\"active\"": "")>Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could do something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "linkText",
    "actionName",
    null,             // routeValues
    new { @class = // just build an expression here to return the class name }
```

Comment: I need to know how to add a class dependant on the current route, see amended question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `ViewContext.RouteData.Values`

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About",
    new { @class = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] })
```

This should add the name of the current action as the link's CSS class.

Or, without HtmlHelpers:

```
<a href="/About" class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"])">
    About
</a>
```